# How shall I make this form automatically identify the user who is logged in as author

Tags: django, django-forms, user-input

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
   model=Post
   form_class=PostForm
   template_name='add_post.html'


from operator import mod
from turtle import title
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['title','body','author','category']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the form_valid method of your CreateView.  You probably don't want to include author in the form.

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'add_post.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'category']
```

Answer (score 0):

Django forms allow you to set initial values, this is how you can pass in the current user in the view. You won't be able to do this directly in your forms.py file because it doesn't receive the request as an argument.

```
form = PostForm(initial={'author': self.request.user})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```py
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'add_post.html'

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'initial': {'author': self.request.user}})
        return kwargs
```